# Access VBA - data provider or other service returned an e_fail status

Tags: vba

could you please help me understand what-s wrong with the below code:

```
Private Function FillCalendar()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ssql As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim i As Integer
Dim Records As Integer
ssql = "SELECT Format(Availability.AvailabilityDate,'mmm dd ddd') AS MyDate FROM Availability WHERE HotelId=3 AND Month( Availability.AvailabilityDate)=Month(Now()) GROUP BY Availability.AvailabilityDate"
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.Open ssql, cnn
Records = rst.RecordCount
For i = 1 To Records
Me("Text" & i).Visible = True
Me("Text" & i).Value = rst.Fields!MyDate
If InStr(Me("Text" & i).Value, "sat") Or InStr(Me("Text" & i).Value, "sun") Then
Me("Text" & i).BackColor = RGB(179, 45, 0)
Else
Me("Text" & i).BackColor = RGB(0, 114, 188)
End If
rst.MoveNext
Next i
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

The code stucks at **Records = rst.RecordCount** and cannot figure out why.
My table called Availability is really simple:

1. AvailabilityId Autonumber Long Integer (Primary Key)
2. RoomTypeId   Number (Foreign Key)
3. HotelId Number (Foreign Key)
4. AvailabilityDate    Date/Time (Format: ShortDate)
5. AvailableRooms Number (Long Integer -    Default Value: 0)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your Query ran through the table and found no matching results.

Try this to check if any records were found:

```
if rst.EOF = false Then
    Records = rst.RecordCount
else 
    Debug.Print "No records returned :/"
End if
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it still shows the error. Now the code stucks at if rst.EOF = false Then

Answer (score 0):

at the end I managed to solve the issue by changing a bit my sql statement and my code:

```
Private Function FillDates()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ssql As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim i As Integer
Dim Records As Integer
ssql = "SELECT AvailabilityDate FROM Availability WHERE Month(AvailabilityDate)=Month(Now()) GROUP BY AvailabilityDate"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.Open ssql, cnn
Records = rst.RecordCount
For i = 1 To Records
Me("Text" & i).Value = rst.Fields!AvailabilityDate
Me("Text" & i).Value = Format(Me("Text" & i), "mmm dd ddd")
If InStr(Me("Text" & i).Value, "sab") Or InStr(Me("Text" & i).Value, "dom") Then
Me("Text" & i).BackColor = RGB(179, 45, 0)
Else
Me("Text" & i).BackColor = RGB(0, 114, 188)
End If
rst.MoveNext
Next i
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Thanks for your help